# select Condition in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `package` :

```
id  name    validity
1   Free     NULL
2   Basic    90
4   Featured 80 
5   Premium  70
```

And I have another table ads

```
id  posted_on   title package_id 
1   2016-09-29  test   1
2   2015-09-29  test2  2
3   2016-07-29  test3  4
```

I have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM ads AS ad WHERE (SELECT datediff(curdate(), posted_on) AS datecount) <= 180
```

I want to fetch this `180` from table `package`

like

```
if (package_id  == 2){
  instead of 180 it will be 90 fetched form package table    
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this through single SQL Query

Comment: you can use CASE.. THEN clause

Comment: Really strange. Why did you give the table an alias? Why did you use a subquery? And then: Why did give that subquery an alias? You are not using any of them in your query.

Comment: Actually I modified the Query from a long Query Forgot to remove the Alias.My Bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the intent of the query to use the validity value in package, if so, then a join will be perfect for you...

```
select ads.*, package.name, package.validity
  from ads
  join package on (   package.id=ads.package_id
                  and (  datediff(curdate(),ads.posted_on)<=package.validity
                      or package.validity is null))
```

Answer (score 0):

First: I don't get your query. Why using a subquery instead just doing that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ads
WHERE datediff(curdate(), posted_on) <= 180
```

And then, change it that way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ads 
WHERE 
    datediff(curdate(), posted_on) <= case when package_id = 2 then 90 else 180 end
```

I removed all the aliases in my answer as they are not used in your query anyway.

Comment: Alright Great this is working perfect.However can you please also suggest the query for NULL value ?  I do not want to have this where condition for package_id = 1

Comment: What should be NULL?

Comment: In package table when id = 1 validity is NULL So  Just remove where condition for package_id = 1